# How can we create a CI/CD Pipeline for Angular 8 code in Bitbucket-server to be deployed in Azure Cloud?

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-server

I am new to Azure Cloud. I need to set up a CI/CD pipeline that will run the following tasks and Deploy the build to Azure Cloud Web App server , every time new changes are pushed to a particular branch in Bitbucket-server.

Following are the tasks :

(A) Run npm install
(B) Run ng build --prod
(C) Run ng tests
(D) Deploy the dist/App_Name build to /wwwroot folder in Azure Cloud.

I tried to pull code from Bitbucket-server under Deployment Center from Azure Cloud, but unable to find any option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your app service, you should see the Bit Bucket option under Deployment Center.

[image: Azure Deployment Center Blade]

Once you click Bitbucket, you click the 'Authorize' button at the bottom of the blade which will then open the Atlassian login screen. From there, you should be able to select your bitbucket repo.